# What is the right way of building and running repos using Yarn Workspaces?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I've been working on a project using *monorepo* and leveraging *yarn workspaces*.

It consists of several apps and common, e.g.

- "server" (TS/Node app),
- "web" (React app with Material UI),
- "common" (Common JS code used in all apps) , etc.

I am having a hard time understanding what the build and run process should look like in this case.

What I do is:

- Building "common"
- Building each app individually ("server", "web", etc.)
- Then in order to run it I need `node_modules`, so I copy that from the root of my monorepo into each of the app builds.
- Then I deliver this built code + node_modules to remote servers (each app separately) where I start the app.

The problem here is that root `node_modules` contains dependencies of all the apps I have in my monorepo, e.g. MaterialUI that is not needed at all for "server" node app. As a result each ready-to-ship app weighs over 400MB which is too much.

What I've tried: My first though was that I could move each app out of the monorepo for build purposes and build it individually (expecting to get only what is specified in their own package.json) but they, as I quickly realized, have dependencies on commons from monorepo so the apps can't be built this way.

So it seems to me that I am missing something and not doing it the right way, would anyone please help me out?

Thanks!